# A Frostman-type result for measures satisfying uniform lower density conditions

Tags: harmonic-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a finite, compactly supported, non-zero measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ for an integer $d$. Let $B(x,r)$ denote the ball of radius $r>0$ centered at $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$. For $\delta \in [0,d]$, we define two conditions: $\mu$ satisfies (C1)-$\delta$ if

$$ \mu(B(x,r)) \leq r^\delta $$

for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $r >0$; and $\mu$ satisfies (C2)-$\delta$ if

$$ \mu(B(x,r)) \geq r^\delta$$

for all $r \in (0,1]$ and $x \in \text{supp}(\mu)$, the closed support of $\mu$.

Frostman's Lemma characterizes the sets which support measures satisfying (C1)-$\delta$.

**Frostman's Lemma.** *A Borel set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ supports a non-zero measure satisfying (C1)-$\delta$ if and only if $A$ has positive $\delta$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.*

I am interested in a complimentary result concerning measures which satisfy (C2)-$\delta$. Observe that any non-empty set supports a point measure, which satisfies (C2)-$0$ and hence satisfies (C2)-$\delta$ for any $\delta > 0$. So any non-empty set trivially supports a measure satisfying (C2)-$\delta$. The question is rather when a given set is *equal* to the closed support of such a measure. In this case we only need consider closed sets. We will also restrict to $A$ being compact.

It can be shown using a covering argument that if $A$ is equal to the support of a (C2)-$\delta$ measure, then its Hausdorff dimension is at most $\delta$. This gives a necessary condition. The problem is then as follows.

**Problem.** *Give a sufficient (or necessary and sufficient) condition (e.g. in terms of Hausdorff measure) on a compact set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ which implies the existence of a finite measure $\mu$ satisfying (C2)-$\delta$ such that the closed support of $\mu$ equals $A$.*

Comment: Technically, the condition should be something like: one cannot find disjoint balls centered at $K$ of radii less than $1$ with arbitrarily large sum of radii to the power $\delta$. It is, clearly, necessary, but I do not see what use any such condition would be because how is one possibly going to check that besides constructing a measure with (C2)-$\delta$ property?

Comment: Yes, this seems equivalent (or very close to equivalent) to the existence of a measure satisfying (C2)-$\delta$. I am also interested in a potentially sub-optimal condition in terms of Hausdorff dimension. It is plausible that if $\delta < \text{dim}(A)$, then there exists a (C2)-$\delta$ measure whose closed support equals $A$. I am unaware of any counter-examples to this. However, I have never seen a statement like this written anywhere.

Comment: No, you cannot do it in terms of the Hausdorff dimension: that is controlled by just a sequence of very efficient covers, but in between you may have very inefficient ones that do not prevent you from getting a bad packing.

Comment: My understanding is that box / Minkowski dimension does not permit this efficiency -- what about a criterion in terms of that dimension?

Comment: That one is trivial: just take a maximal $2^{-k}$ separated set and put the mass $2^{-k\delta}$ at each point. Then take all $k\in\mathbb Z_+$ and add the resulting measures up. If the box dimension is less than $\delta$, the norms will decay geometrically, so the series will converge. The "packing criterion" actually holds (the proof is pretty much the same as (one of those) for the Frostman lemma; if you are really interested, I can post it later), but it doesn't look so great...

Comment: Thank you, this construction is straightforward enough. Not sure what you mean precisely by the "packing criterion"...

Comment: The one I mentioned in my first comment about disjoint balls. It turns out to be both necessary and sufficient, just like in the Frostman lemma with coverings. Do you want to see the argument?

Answer (score 2):

The equivalence to packing mentioned by Fedja is due to Tricot [1].  See also [2] Sec 5 and [3] sec. 3 for variations and extensions.  The early proofs and most textbooks used dyadic cubes in Euclidean space. But Howroyd  [4], [5] gave the argument in compact metric spaces and this is  included in Mattila's textbook [6]. The packing measure version is in the thesis [7], see also [8].

[1]  C. TRICOT. TWO definitions of fractional dimension. Math. Proc. Camb. Philos. Soc. 91 (1982), 57-74.

[2] S. J. TAYLOR and C. TRICOT. Packing measure, and its evaluation for a Brownian path. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 288 (1985), 679-699.

[3] Cutler, Colleen D. "Strong and weak duality principles for fractal dimension in Euclidean space." In Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, vol. 118, no. 3, pp. 393-410. Cambridge University Press, 1995.

[4] Howroyd, John D. "On dimension and on the existence of sets of finite positive Hausdorff measure." Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society 3, no. 3 (1995): 581-604.

[5] Howroyd, John David. "On the theory of Hausdorff measures in metric spaces." PhD diss., UCL (University College London), 1995.

[6] Mattila, Pertti. Geometry of sets and measures in Euclidean spaces: fractals and rectifiability. No. 44. Cambridge university press, 1999.

[7] Joyce, Helen Janeith. "Packing measures, packing dimensions, and the existence of sets of positive finite measure." PhD diss., UCL (University College London), 1995.

[8] Joyce, Helen, and David Preiss. "On the existence of subsets of finite positive packing measure." Mathematika 42, no. 1 (1995): 15-24.

Comment: Indeed. The full texts of the papers are behind the paywall, so let me ask: do they give proofs for an arbitrary compact metric space (as it should be) or they rely on the Euclidean structure/finite dimension (like it is, to my surprise, for the Frostman lemma in many analysis textbooks)?

Comment: I addressed this in my answer now.

Comment: Thank you for providing these references.